# How to connect PowerBI to AWS dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, powerbi, connector

Has anyone been successful in connecting PowerBI to AWS DynamoDB?

I have seen a couple of posts about setting up an ODBC connection but as I have no familiarity to this, I don't know where to begin. 
Please provide any helpful insight as to connecting my DynamoDB to PowerBI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerBi REST API to do low-level [dynamo query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

Comment: Would this handle pagination of the data is more than 1MB?